# What are my options for a thumb trackball for gaming?

Tags: gaming, mice, trackball

I have used the [Logitech M570](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/wireless-trackball-m570?crid=8) for years, however when I compare the [DPI](http://www.howtogeek.com/182702/mouse-dpi-and-polling-rates-explained-do-they-matter-for-gaming/) on it to normal modern gaming mice it seems lackluster. I also would like to use all my fingers for buttons in games that require a lot of different keys and I can't help but feel they are wasted on the two + scroll that the mouse has.

I have also ordered a Japanese mouse call the [Elcom M-XT1URBK](http://www2.elecom.co.jp/products/M-XT1URBK.html) with the promise of more DPI options and more buttons. Although I did like the way it was wired and I do currently use it I found three issues that lead me to look for other options:

- The extra button just slows down the trackball so movement can allows for more precision but is hard-coded and can not be  key-bound.
- The mouse acts like it has mouse acceleration [that makes gaming harder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16diwK6HWbI). (I may be wrong about this but so far it looks like it.)
- The size is small I find my hands cramping after a few matches of an intense game (about an hours use). My older *"M570"* mouse did not do this.

---

> What are my options for a thumb trackball for gaming (aside from the two listed)?

Comment: Trackballs are usually used for precision (drawing), not high-speed actions (gaming). The market will be limited.

Comment: If your Logitech mouse still works fine you might be interested to know that recent studies have shown that higher DPI actually does not increase precision for the purposes of gaming once you pass a certain minimum. If you still like your mouse and are simply looking to increase the amount of buttons you can easily access, something like a razer orbweaver chroma might be more up to your requirements. The gist of these is that you put your left hand on it and have easier access to a greater number of buttons than on a conventional keyboard due to modifier keys.

Comment: Thank you for the comment it is interesting that DPI stops giving an advantage after a certain level. I do in fact own a (non-chroma) **orb-weaver** and it provides a lot of extra buttons (this is good). However, because WASD is on my left if I am moving I was hoping to use the pinky finger on the right for since it currently does nothing. (On a side note I also own two **stinkyboards** for extra buttons but I find it hard to use for anything aside from jump and crouch).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you liked the Logitech M570 they now have the [MX Ergo Plus](https://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/mx-ergo-wireless-trackball-mouse), it has received [favorable reviews](https://techreport.com/review/32629/logitech-mx-ergo-trackball-reviewed/3) with some minor complaints; price being the biggest concern.

There's also the Elecom [M-XPT1MRBK](http://www2.elecom.co.jp.e.gj.hp.transer.com/products/M-XPT1MRBK.html) for a lower price, receiving favorable mention in the above review. The red trackball isn't for show, it improves the sensor's tracking.

[image: Elecom M-XPT1MRBK]

Comment: Those who might be interested in actually purchasing the [MX Ergo Plus can find the best price here](https://pcpartpicker.com/product/3j38TW/logitech-mx-ergo-advanced-wireless-trackball-for-windows-pc-and-mac) with Amazon currently being the cheapest purveyor at $79.77.

Comment: Thank you, although these have the same amount of buttons, the better sensor and favorable reviews is enough for me to upgrade.